# mrgraph: Bigger gap between groups

Tags: graph, stata

I am using `mrgraph` to create hbars of multiresponse vars. I want there to be a bigger gap inb etween the different groups.

Example code:

```
clear
input mr1 mr2 mr3 group
1 0 0 1
0 0 0 2
1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1
0 0 0 2
1 1 0 2
end
mrgraph hbar mr1-mr3, by(group, gap(30))
```

According to the docs `gap()` should widen the gap in between the grouped bars. It doesn't change anything however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mrgraph` is from SSC.

```
oversubopts(gap(3))
```

or

```
oversubopts(gap(300))
```

shows a way to tune the gap between groups.

By the way, a simple `reshape` such as

```
gen id = _n

reshape long mr , i(id) j(question)
```

makes many graph commands much easier.